# Build error "Unable to find version 7.0.0.0 Microsoft.Web.Administration "in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013, nuget, dllimport

Greeting everyone,
I receive a build error from visual studio 2013 when i tried to debug my c# code, the error i received is "Unable to find version 7.0.0.0 of package Microsoft.Web.Administration", i need the Microsoft.Web.Administration for service manager class in my code, i also tried to copy the Microsoft.Web.Administration dll from my c drive to package folder in my project but it didnt works, anyone have idea of how to solve these?[the link to my screenshot of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7gG7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling the DLL file with NuGet in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: That's not the solution! https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/05/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know/